# Getting all records two `has_many, through` relationships away

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a couple models

```
class AAA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bbbs, through: :some_other_model
end

class BBB < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cccs, through: :yet_another_model
end
```

Assuming I have a reference to an instance of `AAA`, how can I get a flat list of all `CCCs` without resorting to inefficient patterns like `a.bbbs.map { |x| x.cccs }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since RoR 3.1 you can nest `has_many :through` associations.

From [3.1 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html):

> Associations with a :through option can now use any association as the
>   through or source association, including other associations which have
>   a :through option and has_and_belongs_to_many associations.

In your example:

```
class AAA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bbbs, through: :some_other_model
  has_many :cccs, through: :bbbs
end

AAA.first.cccs # => [ccc1, ccc2, ...]
```

Comment: I already tried this and it didnt workk. Maybe it was just a stupid syntax error that i didnt notice. Ill try again.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what was different this time around but it seems to be working just fine now. Thanks!